# -ms-filter vs filter What's the difference?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, filter

What's the difference between between IE's `filter` and `-ms-filter` properties? If I use one should I use them both? Do they do the same thing, but each work on only certain versions of IE?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Microsoft introduced `-ms-filter` to make Internet Explorer more standards-compliant (CSS 2.1 requires vendor extensions to have vendor prefix). As the syntax of original `filter` property is not CSS 2.1 compliant, IE8+ requires the value of the `-ms-filter` property to be enclosed in quotation marks.

```
filter: alpha(opacity=40);
-ms-filter: "alpha(opacity=40)";
```

`-ms-filter` is supported in IE8+, legacy `filter` property is, as far as I know, for backwards compatibility supported in all versions of Internet Explorer.

Related link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/09/08/microsoft-css-vendor-extensions.aspx

Please note that support for filters may be removed in IE10.

Comment: I'm using IE8 and filter works but -ms-filter does not. Any ideas?

Comment: @xr280xr Make sure that the browser uses IE8 standards mode to render the webpage.

Comment: You're right. I was just going to post back that it's running in Quirks mode which is totally messing it up.

Answer (score 1):

> -ms-filter property
>
> Sets  or retrieves the filter or collection of filters that are applied to the object. Note   As of Windows Internet
> Explorer 9 this feature was deprecated. As of Internet Explorer 10
> this feature was removed and should no longer be used.

[-ms-filter property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530752(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score -1):

I believe `-ms` is the vendor prefix for some of the new CSS3 properties while `filter` is an older property meant for IE 6-8(I could be wrong on IE 6, but I know for sure it's used in IE 8). Here's more information on where `-ms` is used: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531207(VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531207%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: If I remember correctly, all of them will support `filter`, but it might only be IE 9 that supports `-ms-filter`.

Comment: No. There is no such CSS3 property called filter.

Comment: All modern browsers ignore the filter property as it is non-standard and not a CSS3 property. Run it through the validator and it will be flagged as an error.

Comment: @Rob You're correct, I accidentally had `-ms-filter`, thank you for correcting my oversight! `filter` may not validate, but it is certainly useful for trying to make things cross-browser compatible.

Comment: Well, again, you should use ms-filter. It's the same thing but will validate.

Comment: @Rob It won't validate, just like any other vendor extension. Also, `-ms-filter` is not supported in IE7 and lower.

Comment: @duri - Vendor extensions are valid CSS. The validator has extensions enabled but extensions still show as errors. I thought that had been fixed.

Comment: well, as long as it matters, it validates at current moment. Only problem is to make some nasty stylesheets ... for example, in Wordpress ... to have two stylesheets ... and to include somehow condidtional comments hamdled stylesheets.