# How to override a filter:none in CSS

Tags: html, css, filter, internet-explorer-7

I have an **IE7** specific stylesheet which applies `filter:none;` I have no access to this file so can not simply remove the line. I need to somehow override it via **CSS**, to ignore the `filter:none;` being set.

I have tried using `filter:;` `filter: -;` and `filter: !important;` which should cause the filter attribute to be invalid, but the filter is still being set.

Is it possible to do this without removing the line in the IE7 specific stylesheet or use of javascript/jquery?

---

**answer:**

to fix my specific problem of this, it was **not possible to simply override the** `filter` with  a `null` equivalent as i was asking. As an answer below suggests, it must be overridden by applying the filter directly to where i wanted to override.

**IE7 Specific Stylesheet:**

```
.div.example { 
    filter:none;
}
```

overridden by:
**Generic Stylesheet:**

```
.div.example {
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#7F000000,endColorstr=#7F000000);
}
```

Comment: Did you tried this `filter: initial;`?

Comment: Check this answer out, it may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12780511/how-does-a-css-rule-override-another-css-rule

Comment: @prakash2089 just tried this, same difference as above, `filter:none` still being applied

Comment: It's not possible. You need to set `filter` to exactly what you want it to be, there's no way to set it to "what it was before `filter: none`".

Comment: @thirtydot you are right

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***Extracted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900647/ms-filter-vs-filter-whats-the-difference#answer-6901105)***

> Microsoft introduced -ms-filter to make Internet Explorer more
>   standards-compliant (CSS 2.1 requires vendor extensions to have vendor
>   prefix). As the syntax of original filter property is not CSS 2.1
>   compliant, IE8+ requires the value of the -ms-filter property to be
>   enclosed in quotation marks.

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false)" /* IE 8+ */;
filter: none !important; /* IE 7 and the rest of the world */
```

**As you said, you need to override an existing style, so append `!important`**

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false) !important";
```

If you were wondering, quotations **ARE** required for this microsoft (-ms) vendor prefix. As you see this use case uses MS's gradients, interject that with whatever filter property you wish to override.

Answer (score -1):

In **IE6** and **IE7** filters apply only to elements in which the property is set **hasLayout**. To remove **hasLayout** you can via addition to an element of one of the following properties and values:

```
    position: static;
    float: none;
    width: auto; 
    height: auto; 
    overflow: visible;
    writing-mode: lr-tb | rl-tb | bt-rl;
    zoom: normal.
```